# How to search for only inventory items using SuiteTalk

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I'm using C# in VS 2013.

I use this code:

```
    var request = new ItemSearchBasic
    {
        type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField
        {
            searchValue = new string[]
            {
                "_inventoryItem"
            },
            @operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
            operatorSpecified = true
        }

    };
```

and I get not just inventory items but other types of item too.

My soap request looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <passport xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <email xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">xxxxxxxxx</email>
            <password xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">********************</password>
            <account xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">xxxxxxxxx</account>
            <role internalId="3" xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
        </passport>
        <searchPreferences xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <bodyFieldsOnly>false</bodyFieldsOnly>
            <pageSize>5</pageSize>
        </searchPreferences>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <search xmlns="urn:messages_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <searchRecord xsi:type="q1:ItemSearchBasic" xmlns:q1="urn:common_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <q1:type operator="anyOf">
                    <searchValue xmlns="urn:core_2014_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">_inventoryItem</searchValue>
                </q1:type>
            </searchRecord>
        </search>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The NetSuite help does't mention how to filter by item type and I've guessed this method from various non-NetSuite web pages.

If I remove the filter on type then my search returns inventoryItem, serializedInventoryItem, lotNumberedInventoryItem and nonInventoryPurchaseItem.

If I use the _inventoryItem filter then I get inventoryItem, serializedInventoryItem and lotNumberedInventoryItem. So maybe NetSuite considers serializedInventoryItem and lotNumberedInventoryItem to both be inventoryItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to distinguish (Inventory) Items in more detail, you can use 'isSerialItem', 'isLotItem' and 'subType' (for purchase/resale/sale) search filters in the search request.