# How to search for "Lot Numbered Assembly/Bill of Materials" items by external ID using SuiteTalk

Tags: c#, netsuite

WSDL 2014.2. C# in Visual Studio 2013.

I can get "Inventory Item" items using this code:

```
var recordRefs = new List<RecordRef>();

foreach (string externalId in ExternalIds)
{
    recordRefs.Add(new RecordRef
    {
        externalId = externalId,
        type = RecordType.inventoryItem,
        typeSpecified = true
    });
}

var request = new ItemSearchBasic
{
    externalId = new SearchMultiSelectField
    {
        @operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf,
        operatorSpecified = true,
        searchValue = recordRefs.ToArray()
    }
};

SearchResult response = SuiteTalkConnection.Service.search(request);
```

However, if I change `type = RecordType.inventoryItem` to `type = RecordType.lotNumberedAssemblyItem` then I don't get results. I am specifying correct values as external IDs.

I have tried all sorts of variations on the above, including ItemSearch instead of ItemSearchBasic but I never get results.

It doesn't help that I can find zero NetSuite documentation on searching for specific item types.

Answer (score 1):

I think answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628083/how-to-search-for-only-inventory-items-using-suitetalk) would also work in this case. Try using type as "assemblyItem" only and use an additional searchFilter "isLotItem" and set it to true.